# Bootstrap centering on zooming

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dilemma and I can't figure this out. Saying I have a logo and a nav next to it like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="span4">
        <img src="">/*Logo*/</div>
    <div class="span8">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Link1</li>
                <li>Link2</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I zoom in the page and my menu get under the logo i want both to get centered. Is that possible?

Comment: You will need some `@media` queries to apply to lower resolutions, and then work on centering your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
<div class="content row-fluid"> //Add this
```